# Need help joining tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am a MySQL newbie, so sorry if this is a dumb question..

These are my tables.

**student table:**
SID (primary)
student_name
advisor (foreign key to faculty.facultyID)
requested_advisor (foreign key to faculty.facultyID)

**faculty table:**
facultyID (primary key)
advisor_name

I want to query a table that shows everything in the student table, but I want advisor and requested_advisor to show up as names, not the ID numbers.

so like it displays like this on the webpage:
*Student Name: Jane Smith

SID: 860123456

Current Advisor: John Smith

Requested advisor: James Smith*

not like this

*Student Name: Jane Smith

SID: 860123456

Current Advisor: 1

Requested advisor: 2*

```
SELECT student.student_name, SID, student_email, faculty.advisor_name
FROM student
INNER JOIN faculty ON student.advisor = faculty.facultyID;
```

this comes out close, but I don't know how to get the requested_advisor to show up as a name.

Comment: Wow, thank you guys. I didn't know you could do that! Thanks for the speedy answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join with faculty twice using different aliases,

```
SELECT 
student.student_name, 
SID, 
student_email, 
fac1.advisor_name AS 'advisor', 
fac2.advisor_name AS 'requested advisor'
FROM student
INNER JOIN faculty fac1 ON student.advisor = fac1.facultyID
INNER JOIN faculty fac2 ON student.requested_advisor = fac2.facultyID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.student_name, s.SID, f.advisor_name, f2.advisor_name
FROM student s
JOIN faculty f ON s.advisor = f.facultyID
JOIN faculty f2 ON s.requested_advisor = f2.facultyID
```

Should output

```
Jane Smith | 860123456 | John Smith | James Smith
```